# Twitter+oauth share url

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'm using the Twitter+oauth library on iOS. Every thing is working fine but I can't figure out how to pass url in the message I want to be on twitter. It's supposed to be reduced by t.co to not use all the maximum characters allowed on a tweet.

When I directly post my sentence with the url on twitter, the whole sentence is tweeted, but when I post this sentence via my application (using twitter+oauth and the sendUpdate function) it's cutting off half of my sentence, because it has too much characters.

How can I specify to Twitter that it has to reduce the url via t.co ?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq

Comment: It is saying that I don't need any extra API calls. But it seems to not working.

Comment: are you urls rfc1738 Conform? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738

Comment: It's a simple link to my app in itunes :
http://itunes.apple.com/app/kids-fun-plus-70-jeux-et-activites/id469783442?ls=1&mt=8
I guess it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using bit.ly url shortener.